# Keyboard shortcuts with JavaScript, not working correctly on Firefox

Tags: javascript

Can't disable the default behaviour of Ctrl+S in Firefox.
Can't disable the Ctrl+P behaviour in IE

What's wrong with my code...? I cant figure out.
Thanks.

```
// Keyboard shortcuts
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 17) {
        isCtrl = false;
    }
};
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 17) {
        isCtrl = true;
    }
    if (e.which === 79 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+O
        e.preventDefault();
        Open();
    }
    if (e.which === 83 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+S
        e.preventDefault();
        Save();
    }
    if (e.which === 80 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+P
        e.preventDefault();
        Print();
    }
    if (e.which === 72 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+H
        e.preventDefault();
        Help();
    }
};
```

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** Firefox (and likely other browsers) now use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode` and may return '0' instead of the previous values. The new use: `alert(event.key);` will alert 's' or 'S' for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
e = e || window.event;
e.which = e.which || e.keyCode;
```

sample:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.which = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (e.which === 79 && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl+O
        e.preventDefault();
        Open();
    }
    if (e.which === 83 && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl+S
        e.preventDefault();
        Save();
    }
    if (e.which === 80 && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl+P
        e.preventDefault();
        Print();
    }
    if (e.which === 72 && e.ctrlKey) {
        // Ctrl+H
        e.preventDefault();
        Help();
    }
};
```

Comment: `key = e.which || e.keyCode`

Comment: It seems the default behaviour of Ctrl+S is still applied along with my function Save() in Firefox.

Comment: @drdrb i get it ,change onkepdown to onkeypress

Answer (score 0):

You are using e.which to determine if the key was control as well as the keycode itself

that's like saying `if(e.which==17 && e.which=79);`
See what I am getting at?
Use `e.ctrlKey` to determine if control was pressed
    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
        e.which = e.which || e.charCode;

```
        isCtrl = e.ctrlKey

};
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e.which = e.which || e.charCode;

        isCtrl = e.ctrlKey
    if (e.which === 79 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+O
        e.preventDefault();
        Open();
    }
    if (e.which === 83 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+S
        e.preventDefault();
        Save();
    }
    if (e.which === 80 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+P
        e.preventDefault();
        Print();
    }
    if (e.which === 72 && isCtrl === true) {
        // Ctrl+H
        e.preventDefault();
        Help();
    }
};
```

javascript

Answer (score 0):

In short you need to use `setTimeout` unfortunately, I [blogged about this issue](https://www.jabcreations.com/blog/javascript-ctrl+s-save-forms-and-save-all-forms) in 2014. It's a bit of a hack but it works...

```
window.onkeypress = function(event)
{
 if (event.ctrlKey && event.key=='s')
 {
  event.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {form_submit(event);},1);
 }
}


function form_submit(event)
{
 alert('trigger your code here...');
}
```